# Uncaught Error: Method not found cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to run an old cordova application but despite the fact that the build finishes without any erros, i'am getting the  following error while debugging from android device with chrome: 
" Uncaught Error: Method not found " for method

```
nativeApiProvider.get().exec(service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

in cordova.js line 863.

The onDeviceReady callback is not firing at all.

I've tried re-installing and updating cordova platform and plug ins several times but with no luck.

I suppose the problem occures when a plug-in runs native java code. If so, how can i find which one causes the problem?
Maybe it's something else?

The specific application has been developed in an older cordova version (not sure which one).

Comment: does logcat tell you anything more than the javascript console does?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to start a Cordova app that has a plugin installed. You cannot run apps with native plugins in a browser. You must generate an APK file to install it on devices. Would you like me to point you to the right direction?

Comment: I forgot to mention, but i am debugging on a device already. There was a cordova.js file inside www folder (since the app was developed on a older version of cordova, i guess) that i deleted and since then everything is runnging smoothly. There was a conflict between the multiple cordova.js files that existed on the project. Thanks anyway